# firestore firebase problem: how to update the document without specifying the name of the document

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to access UserPrefs and access the weather_location directly without specifying the document name. How can I do that ?

```
const res = await firestore().collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('userPrefs').doc().set({weather_location: location});
```

Comment: There are three documents in that collection. If you don't know the ID, then how do you know which one(s) to update?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the collection UserPrefs and find all the documents that contain a field "weather_location", then update all of them or only one.

something like:

```
const querySnapshot = await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('userPrefs')
    .where('weather_location', '>', '')
    .get();

const firstDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];

await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('userPrefs')
    .doc(firstDoc.id)
    .set({weather_location: location});
```